# Remotely opening an application on device

Tags: android, nvidia, tvos, apple-tv, roku

I recently went through ROKU SSDP (ECP)  APIs which allow opening application on Roku programatically using deviceIp from a computer on same network.
Reference : https://developer.roku.com/docs/developer-program/debugging/external-control-api.md

I was wondering if there is a way to do open an application remotely on android or iOS devices. The devices over which I want this are Nvidia Shield, Apple TV Gen 4/5. I know there are solutions where I can install a custom application on the device and invoke it passing messages to application, but that is requiring me to build and maintain this custom application which I want to avoid.

I have a linux and Mac Machine on same network as the device to do this. I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Apple TV runs tvOS, not iOS, although the two are similar.  There is no published remote control API for tvOS.

Comment: Nvidia Shield ?

Comment: For Android check [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) which enables things like [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)